# props not updated in html rendered, but updated in console.log from render()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got a nav menu listening to scroll using react-scroll lib.

working :
I save activated Element to my store, so each time I scroll over a new element, my store knows which element is 'active'.

When I display my nav menu, I want to check which element is active from my store and add a class on some nav element. I can't do it with react-scroll because my elements are nested (and I want to highlight some intermediate nav element depending on the current react-scroll active element).

Anyway, when I scroll, store is updated, component listening to this store value is re-rendered, render method is called, console.logs from inside the render() display the right value of "selectedMenu" (this is my store value), ** BUT **, the html generated from the return() of the render() do not update the "selectedMenu" variable value.

For information on first display selectedMenu is empty as nothing has been clicked / scrolled. This empty value remains in the return of the render, but is updated in the console.log inside the render().

Getting crazy...

```
render(){
    const {opened, menuId, sub, selectedMenu, selectedCat, setActiveDispatch, anchorKey, titleKey, subClickedDispatch} = this.props;

    console.log('****** selectedMenu : ' + selectedMenu); // displaying the updated value
    console.log('****** selectedCat : ' + selectedCat); // displaying the updated value

    const subData = sub.map((subcat, index)=> {
        console.log("inside map & selectedMenu : " + selectedMenu); // displaying the updated value
        console.log("inside map & selectedCat : " + selectedCat); // displaying the updated value
        return (
            <div key={menuId+'_'+index}>
                <SubMenuChildren>
                    <Link isDynamic={true} offset={-80} onSetActive={(to)=>setActiveDispatch(to)} to={subcat[anchorKey]+"_top_empty"} spy={true} smooth={true} duration={500}><ListItem innerDivStyle={{padding:'0px 0 0px 0px'}} style={{height:'0px'}}></ListItem></Link>
                </SubMenuChildren>
                <SubMenuChildren>
                    {/* selectedMenu NOT UPDATED : is empty, subcat[anchorKey] is ok */}
                    <div>test : {selectedMenu} {subcat[anchorKey]}</div> 
                    {/* selectedCat NOT UPDATED : is empty, subcat[anchorKey] is ok */}
                    <div>test : {selectedCat} {subcat[anchorKey]}</div> 

                    {/* test is always false as selectedMenu is always empty */}
                    <Link isDynamic={true} className={selectedMenu==subcat[anchorKey]?'active':''} offset={-80} onSetActive={(to)=>setActiveDispatch(to)} to={subcat[anchorKey]} spy={true} smooth={true} duration={500} onClick={()=>subClickedDispatch(subcat)}><ListItem innerDivStyle={{padding:'5px 0 5px 5px'}} style={this.style.navSubElements} hoverColor='transparent' primaryText={ subcat[titleKey] }></ListItem></Link>
                </SubMenuChildren>
            </div>
        );
    });

    return (
        <div className={opened?'subMenu open':'subMenu close'}>
            <div>retest : {selectedMenu}</div> {/* value is updated  !*/}
            {subData}           
        </div>
    );
}
```

And here is my mapStateToProps :

```
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
clickedMain: state.appReducer.clickedMain,
selectedMenu: state.appReducer.selectedMenu,
selectedCat: state.appReducer.selectedCat});
```

Answer (score 0):

Damn it !

Someone from IRC #reactjs just found it. 
Problem comes from  component (not posted here) which doesn't update (shouldComponentUpdate always return false). Removing this SCU and all works back.